# Populate String with Firestore

Tags: android, arrays, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have this spinner which is populated by an array of strings.
I tried replacing this for a Document I have in [firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6WSX.jpg) although the result I get is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6WSX.jpg), before the app crashes.

Could I please get some help on how to populate my array with the information from my Document? Been around this for day without any luck :/

Thanks

```
    private var db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()


   private var spinnerArray: Array<Task<QuerySnapshot>> =  arrayOf(db.collection("KitList").get()
           .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
               if (task.isSuccessful) {
                   spinnerArray = task.result as Array<Task<QuerySnapshot>>

 //or however you get your document array
                   for (document in task.result) {
                       Log.d("weight05", document.id + " => " + document.data)
                   }
               } else {
                   Log.w("error", "Error getting documents.", task.exception)
               }
           })
    var newKitList = mutableListOf<String>()



override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_kit_list)
    var addButton = addKitItemBtn




    val spinner = newKitItemSpinner
    val spinnerArrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerArray)
    //selected item will look like a spinner set from XML
    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
    spinner.adapter = spinnerArrayAdapter

    val kitList = newKistListView
    val listViewAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, newKitList)
    kitList.adapter = listViewAdapter




    addButton.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            val selectedItem = spinner.selectedItem.toString()
            newKitList.add(selectedItem)
            listViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    })
```

**ERROR LOG:**

```
0-10 16:28:48.176 23462-23462/com.reecreate.woderator2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: com.reecreate.woderator2, PID: 23462
                                                                      java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task[]
                                                                          at com.reecreate.woderator2.Controller.NewKitListActivity$spinnerArray$1.onComplete(NewKitListActivity.kt:27)
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzf.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: Can you please add error log which you are getting?

Comment: Only saw this now sorry. Going to edit my question with the error

Comment: Any ideas @pRaNaY ?